# The Holy Water of the Sotah: what does it symbolize?

Tags: commentaries, chasidut-hasidism, parshat-nasso, sotah

The Sotah (the woman suspected of marital infidelity), was instructed to drink the bitter waters [(Bamidbar, chapter 5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.5.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) as a consequence for her behaviour.

> And the priest shall bring her near, and set her before the L-rd, and the priest shall take holy water in an earthen vessel; and of the dust that is on the floor of the tabernacle shall the priest take, and put it into the water.and the priest shall set the woman before the Lord, and loosen the hair of the woman’s head, and put the offering of memorial in her hands, which is the meal offering of jealousy. And the priest shall have in his hand the bitter water that causes the curse.

On of the "ingredients" was מים קדשים - holy water. [Rashi explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.5.17.1?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D&with=Lexicon&lang2=en) why the term holy applies to this water.

The [Rabbeinu Bahya (ad loc.)](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.5.17?lang=bi&with=Rabbeinu%20Bahya&lang2=en) asks the question why specifically water was taken for this "mixture". He explains that water symbolizes the Heavens, whereas dust represents the earth:

> ולקח הכהן מים קדושים בכלי חרש ומן העפר אשר יהיה בקרקע המשכן, “the Priest is to take sacred water in an earthenware vessel, and he shall take from the earth that is at the floor of the Tabernacle, etc.” Why does he have to take water? Because water symbolises the Heaven (the “upper waters”) and from the floor of the Tabernacle, as this symbolises dust, Earth. We have been taught in Sotah 17 that Rava, commenting on the requirement of dust in connection with the procedure involving the Sotah, the woman suspected of marital infidelity, claims that in the event the woman is found innocent (as she claims) she will bear a son similar to Avraham who said of himself: “I am dust and ashes” (Genesis 18,27). If the woman in question was guilty, however, her fate, i.e. death, will be that she returns to “dust.” Thus far the Talmud.

However, I was thinking about a Gemara that explains that matters of Torah are likened to water [(Taanis 7a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.7a.15?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). The Maharal explains [why](https://www.sefaria.org/Derekh_Chayim.6.6.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Water was maybe the most simple substance to use, but I am not looking for that kind of explanations. Water is likened to Torah, as per the Gemara in Taanis 7a. So I was thinking, maybe it has something to do with the fact that the Sotah, which also translates as the "wayward wife" can be a lesson to all of us. If we deviate from the path of Torah. The thing to do is to take water, e.g. to delve into Torah.

**Are there sources that agree with this notion? E.g. that the water can symbolize Torah and the Sotah is deviating from Torah, so what we need to do, is ["come and drink the water"](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.55.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)?**

Comment: The meaning of מים קדשים is better translated as water that is drawn for this specific purpose, as in את מקדשת לי כדת משה וישראל. In other words it is water dedicated with this intention when it is drawn. לשם מצות סוטה.

Comment: Rashi says: The water was taken from the laver. So that seems understandable. Do you have any thoughts on my question? Is this a theme mentioned (ever) in chassidus?

Comment: I’m sure it is discussed extensively but would have to look around to see specifically what is said in regard to your question.

Comment: Wonderful. I came up with this "chiddush" (if it can be called such), and was wondering if there are sources that back it up. That would be wonderful namely.

Comment: @YaacovDeane any success in finding something perhaps?

Comment: I apologize, Shmuel. I haven't had the time to dig around for it yet. Unfortunately, it still remains on my "To-Do List"! הוי׳ יעזור

Comment: @YaacovDeane no problem, thank you! I look forward to it, since I also haven't found any sources on it.

Comment: As I reflect for a moment on your question, your opening statement, that drinking the water was "as a punishment" should be changed. Drinking the water was "a consequence" of her behavior and her husbands suspected charge. The result of drinking the water was either a huge blessing or the opposite. It merely revealed the truth; what had been in doubt previously. Thinking about "erasing G-d's name" in the water also brings to mind the mitzvah of "erasing the memory of Amalek". That Amalek עמלק is gematria doubt ספק.

Comment: @YaacovDeane interesting. I edited my opening. Thank you for observing.

Comment: @YaacovDeane The water is not drawn for this specific purpose.  It's taken from the Kiyor.  Sotah 2:3

Comment: @Heshy I’m looking at your Mishnah reference and not sure what you’re trying to bring out or how this relates to my comment to Shmuel.

Comment: @YaacovDeane You said that the water is drawn for the purpose of the mitzvah of Sotah.  But it's not - it was probably originally drawn for the purpose of the kohanim washing their hands (although I don't even think that requires being drawn lishmah).

Comment: @Heshy You’re certainly entitled to understand the text of the Mishnah whatever way you choose. But simply saying that water was drawn from the Kiyor, doesn’t exclude the idea that this drawn water will be drawn with intent, like the text of the written Torah suggests.

Comment: @Shmuel I looked over the subject this Shabbat. Not finding exactly what you’re looking for, but close. 1st of all, the water is sanctified, like Rashi explains, by coming in physical contact with the inside walls of the Kiyor itself which was also made from the brass mirrors used by the Jewish wives to help make themselves physically attractive to their husbands during the harshest servitude in Egypt. You should look at Sefer Toldot Yaacov Yosef to parshat Naso 5:12 & also Be’er Mayim Chayim by Rabbi Chaim of Chernovitch that relate to your thought.

Comment: @YaacovDeane wonderful, many thanks! I did not find the Toldos Yaakov Yosef there. Please feel free to put those into an answer and I will award all the points to you for the help!